# How does Spring batch remote partitioning work with IBM LSF cluster?

Tags: java, spring-batch

We are using IBM LSF clusters to perform computationally intensive operations and already running numerous jobs on them.

Now, I am doing some POC to evaluate how Spring batch jobs can be used to offload basic job infrastructure and focus on business logic mainly data transformations.

I could not find not find any concrete source to evaluate how jobs distributed in multiple steps can be partitioned and fed to LSF cluster which can process the steps parallely and in a distributed fashion.

Pardon my knowledge if there is already a source available, would you point me to right source or answer here how it can be done?

Comment: Any solution here?

Comment: @ypriverol I changed my approach later to take responsibility of partioning before the job is being submitted to LSF. For Spring batch it needs to know which nodes LSF is submitting the jobs too or a cluster nodes. But this understanding is based on my brief research and should be researched further

Comment: I was thinking that implementing the https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer was enough and that was basically translate Spring batch jobs into LSF jobs. But it also my brief research

Comment: I could not find any reliable https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#partitionHandler which distributes work load on the underlying LSF nodes. I did partitioning on my own which requires a lot of ugly code in bash because 'bsub' implementation is available from shell only.